# Android: RSS feed getting: XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in BufferedReader@216a7d6b)

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-xmlpullparser

I am getting the following exception trying to read an RSS feed:

```
XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.BufferedReader@216a7d6b) 
W/System.err(18802):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2054)
```

I've tried using the ksoap2-android-assembly libraries versions 2.4, 3.0 RC 4, 3.2.0, and 3.4.0 all with the SAME error on this feed:

http://vimeo.com/channels/karnschurch/videos/rss
(Which passes RSS validators just fine)

ENVIRONMENT:
Android Studio 1.1.0
Ubuntu 14.10 x64
Running on a Nexus 4 with 5.0.1

I've used the same code on dozens of other feeds with no errors.  I know others have run into this issue and reported luck with different versions of the ksoap2 library (which is why I tried a few versions).  But, nothing seems to help.  My code is:

```
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
parser.setInput(reader);
parser.nextTag();
return readFeed(parser);
```

It blows up on nextTag() and never gets to readFeed().

Any ideas on how I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just that I was using HttpURLConnection, but the link redirects to HTTPS.  So, I just used HttpsURLConnection instead.